# in windows7,when we open a process ,we get a process handle,I want to know what the relation between process handle and process ID

Tags: windows-7, handle

just as my title ,thanks!!the handle I mentioned is using in  psphandletable!
in windows7,when we open a process ,we get a process handle,I want to know what the relation between process handle and process ID

Comment: There is no relationship between the numerical value of the handle and the process ID.  See [Handles and Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724457(v=vs.85).aspx) for an overview of how handles work.

Comment: thanks,in WRK ,I feel processiD and process handle can be used to find a process,but when I print handle as ulong,it is strange,can I use handle to index handle table manually??thank you very much!

Comment: The way the handle table is implemented is undocumented, and may vary between different versions of Windows.  Besides, I'm not sure it is even accessible from user-mode.  You have to use the documented API, e.g., in order to look up the process ID, call GetProcessId().